# Problem with function arguments and for loop in bash

Tags: bash

Why doesn't this print all the passed arguments, in bash?

```
function abc() {
    echo "$1" #prints the correct argument

    for x in `seq 1 $#`; do
        echo "$x" #doesn't print the 1st, 2nd, etc arguments, but instead 1, 2, ..
    done
}
```

It is printing

```
1
2
3
4
...
```

instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll just add a couple more options to what everyone else has given.  The closest to the way you're trying to write this is to use bash indirect expansion:

```
function abc() {
    for x in `seq 1 $#`; do
        echo "${!x}"    # the ! adds a level of indirection
    done
}
```

...another option if you want to operate on only some of the arguments, is to use array slicing with $@:

```
function def() {
    for arg in "${@:2:3}"; do  # arguments 2 through 4 (i.e. 3 args starting at number 2)
        echo "$arg"
    done
}
```

similarly, `"${@:2}"` will give you all arguments starting at number 2, `"${@:$start:$((end-start+1))}"` will give you arguments $start through $end (the `$((` expression calculates how many arguments there are between $start and $end), etc...

Answer (score 4):

Actually there is a special short-hand for this case:

```
function abc() {
  for arg ; do
    echo "$arg"
  done
}
```

That is, if the `in ...` part is omitted, `arg` loops over the function's argument `$@`.

Incidentally if you have `for arg ; ...` outside of a function, it will iterate over the arguments given on the command line.

Answer (score 2):

The `seq` command returns all numbers from start to stop. What you are calling here is `seq 1 <number_of_arguments_to_abc>`. For example, if you call `abc alpha beta gamma`, then the arguments would be `seq 1 3`, thus you get the numbers 1, 2 and 3.

If you want the arguments to abc instead, the expression is `for x in "$@"`.

Comment: Yes. But assuming I'd want to use the current seq instruction, how would I have to do with echo? I say this because I might not want to go through all the elements. Sometime I will want to start on the 2nd, for example.

Comment: @devoured elysium: I'm sorry, I don't really understand your goal. Please give examples how you want to call `abc`, and what it should output in those cases.

Comment: arguments a b c and i only want b and c

Comment: `function abc() { echo "$1"; shift; for x in "$@" ; do echo "$x" ; done ; }` The magic is the `shift` command, which throws away the (currently) first argument.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print all arguments try this

```
function abc() {
   for arg in $@; do
      echo "$arg"
   done
}
```

Comment: I really recommend to add quotation marks around `$@`, as in `"$@"`. If you don't you get unexpected results if you for example call `abc "String with spaces"`.

Answer (score 1):

The variable **X** holds the literal numbers. You're trying to do *indirection* - substitute **$1** where there's a **$x**. Indirection warps the brain. **$@** provides a simpler mechanism for looping over the arguments - without any adverse effects on your psyche.

```
for x in "$@"; do
  echo $x
done
```

See [the bash man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters) for more details on **$@**.

Comment: Yes, but as explained to DarkDust, I need better granularity. I might just want to iterate over part of the arguments' elements, so I need to know if it possible doing it without $@

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `for arg` form that others have shown. However, to address some things in your question and comments, see the following:

In Bash, it's not necessary to use `seq`. You can use C-style `for` loops:

```
for ((i = 2; i <= $#; i++))
do
    echo "${@:i:1}"
done
```

Which demonstrates array slicing which is another technique you can use in addition to direct iteration (`for arg`) or using `shift`.

An advantage of using either version of `for` is that the argument array is left intact, while shift modifies it. Also, with the C-style form with array slicing, you could skip any arguments you like. This is usually not done to the extent shown below, because it would rely on the arguments following a strict pattern.

```
for ((i = 2; i < $# - 2; i+=2))
```

That bit of craziness would start at the second argument, process every other one and stop before the last two or three (depending on whether `$#` is odd or even).